# Allow proceed to checkout for non mixed defined product categories in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

In woocommerce I am trying to avoid proceed to checkout when cart items are from mixed product categories… The following code is mostly working as I intended:

```
function sv_wc_prevent_checkout_for_category() {

    // set the slug of the category that cannot be mixed from other categories
    $category = 'test';

    // get the product category
    $product_cat = get_term_by( 'slug', $category, 'product_cat' );

    // sanity check to prevent fatals if the term doesn't exist
    if ( is_wp_error( $product_cat ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( sv_wc_is_category_alone_in_cart( $category ) ) {

        //Proceed to checkout
    }
    else { // otherwise post a notice to explain why checkout is blocked 
    wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'hi there! looks like your cart contains products from PREORDER and ONHAND categories, in order to proceed go to cart and dont mixed it.', $category_name ), 'error' ); }   

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'sv_wc_prevent_checkout_for_category' );

function sv_wc_is_category_alone_in_cart( $category ) {

    // check each cart item for our category
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

        // if a product is not in our category, bail out since we know the category is not alone
        if ( ! has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $cart_item['data']->id ) ) {
        return false;
        }
    }

    // if we're here, all items in the cart are in our category
    return true;
}
```

But I have a problem: When cart contain items only from other product categories it doesn't allow proceed to checkout displaying the error message.

To resume:

1. If the cart contains "TEST" product category: Allow "proceed to checkout" (working)
2. If the cart items have mixed product categories ("TEST" and others): NOT allow "proceed to checkout" and display the error message (working)
3. If the cart contains only other product categories (without the "TEST" product category): NOT allow "proceed to checkout" and display the error message (**NOT WORKING**)

How can I make it work **for other product categories**, allowing "proceed to checkout"?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code that will not allow to mix your "test" defined product category with other product categories, displaying an error notice and avoiding checkout:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'prevent_checkout_product_category_based' );
function prevent_checkout_product_category_based() {

    // HERE set the product category slug
    $category = 'test';

    $found = $other = false; // Initializing variables

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // checking for the specific product category
        $term_slugs = wp_get_post_terms( $cart_item['product_id'], 'product_cat', array('fields' => 'slugs') );
        if( in_array($category, $term_slugs) ) {
            $found = true; // Targeted product category found
        }
        elseif( ! in_array($category, $term_slugs) && sizeof($term_slugs) > 0 ){
            $other = true; // Other product categories found
        }
    }
    // If the targeted product category is mixed with other product categories
    if ( $found && $other ) {
        // Display an error notice and avoid checkout
        wc_add_notice( __( "The cart contains products from PREORDER and ONHAND categories and can't be mixed together, to allow checkout." ), 'error' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.